# Can I work with Sharepoint framework without access to Github?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-framework

According to **Set up your SharePoint framework development environment**, I need to install `node.js` and then use its command to download further package (yo and gulp)  from github.  I installed node success with the `.msi` installer.  But yo and gulp have been installed with some warning.

However my dev server cannot direct access Internet and Github.  I fail on almost every step. (e.g. cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-build-web')

Is there any article talk about offline environment or any official source saying github is essential?

Answer (score 0):

We were also facing the same issue while creating SharePoint Framework web parts on our virtual machines(I guess because of proxy).

In order to create the web part your machine should have internet access as it loads so many files from internet.

Also you need to have the access to `GitHub` and `npm-registry` as it loads files from there.

And the error `cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-build-web'` is because `gulpfile.js` is not able to find the this module under `node_modules\@microsoft` folder at line `const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');`

Maybe you can try adding npm proxy in your development server and try creating web part again. But you will need Internet for sure.